# convert multiple segments of DVD to FLV

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, conversion, dvd, flv

I have a DVD of footage that I need to convert to FLV.

I would rather not convert the whole disk as I only need specific segments. Is there a program that I can input start and end times and to get multiple files of these segments?

Can you also advise on the best settings to use for best quality at the smallest file sizes.

I'm working on a Vista 64bit machine.

Thanks.
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of [VLC](http://lifehacker.com/5318807/vlc-10-records-video-from-dvds) lets you interactively record segments.

VLC can also [transcode videos](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode). You could chain the two operations together if you knew the segment start and stop times. You can use these same commands to write out the segments non-interactively without transcoding.

I'm not certain VLC can transcode into flv - you'll need to check that if you intend to use VLC to convert the stream too.

Comment: have you got any examples of the commands i would need to use?

Answer (score 1):

use a movie editing tool (e.g. Windows Moviemaker or [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)) to cut the 'segments' and then convert the clips to flash (e.g. with [Riva FLV Encoder](http://rivavx.com/index.php?encoder))

Comment: can you do that directly from a DVD?

Comment: AFAIK, VirtualDub supports DVD files. if not, check these plug-ins: http://home.comcast.net/~fcchandler/index.html