# How do I convert a DVD to a single FLV file?

Tags: flash, conversion, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert multiple segments of DVD to FLV](https://superuser.com/questions/35717/convert-multiple-segments-of-dvd-to-flv)

I have a DVD that I would like to convert to an FLV object.  How could I do that?

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/35717/convert-multiple-segments-of-dvd-to-flv